# Why does my stock Samsung Galaxy phone/tablet lack some features compared to other Samsung Galaxy models?

Tags: samsung, stock-android, samsung-one-ui

I have Samsung Galaxy M12 on stock Android 12. When I'm reading about Samsung features on the internet (including [samsung](/questions/tagged/samsung)-related questions here), sometimes I found that I don't have such features on my phone, like Secure Folder.

What are the possible reasons for the lack of features?

Comment: Possibly related: [What Are The Differences Between Samsung Firmware Version For Countries In The Same Region?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/66010/44325)

Answer (score 5):

**There are at least 4 possible reasons:**

- Device model
- One UI Core
- Android Go
- Android versions

---

#### Device Model

Newer Samsung phones and tablets tend to have more features despite having the same Android version (One UI version). Example:

- [Dual recording: record the selfie front view video and the main rear view video as separate files](https://www.samsung.com/us/support/answer/ANS00088322/): S22, S23.
- [Edge Lighting](https://www.samsung.com/uk/support/mobile-devices/what-do-the-notification-light-colours-mean-on-my-samsung-galaxy-smartphone/): Note10, S20.

#### One UI Core

[One UI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_UI) is Samsung's customization on Android OS available since Android 9 Pie for the Samsung Galaxy series. While it packs many additional features outside of AOSP, there is also One UI *Core*, the stripped-down version of One UI usually found on budget models such as Galaxy M and A series.

Some known missing features:

- [Bixby](https://www.samsung.com/us/apps/bixby/) (Bixby Routines, Bixby Vision)
- [Easy Mode](https://www.samsung.com/au/support/mobile-devices/using-easy-mode/)
- [Edge Panels](https://www.samsung.com/us/support/answer/ANS00080551/) & [Edge Lighting](https://www.samsung.com/uk/support/mobile-devices/what-is-edge-lighting/)
- [Director's View and Dual recording](https://www.samsung.com/us/support/answer/ANS00088322/)
- [Game Launcher](https://www.samsung.com/global/galaxy/apps/game-launcher/)
- Good Lock
- Link to Windows
- Samsung Knox Security
- Samsung Health
- Samsung Pay/Pay Mini
- Secure Folder

#### Android Go

[Android Go](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Go) is an Android variant optimized for devices with low memory spec. Although not Samsung-specific, some features may be disabled:

- Notification Access
- Do not Disturb
- Picture-in-picture
- VR helper services
- Zen mode

#### Android versions

[Android versions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history) also affect which features are available on the device, although this is also not really Samsung-specific. *(Since there are too many differences, please refer to Wikipedia for the summary of each version)*

---

References:

- One UI Core

  - [MUO - Samsung One UI vs. One UI Core: What's the Difference?](https://www.makeuseof.com/samsung-one-ui-vs-one-ui-core/)
  - [Sammy Fans - Samsung One UI vs One UI Core: Here’s the difference](https://www.sammyfans.com/2021/04/27/one-ui-vs-one-ui-core-difference/)
  - [Guiding Tech - Samsung One UI vs One UI Core: What’s the Difference](https://www.guidingtech.com/samsung-one-ui-vs-one-ui-core-difference/)
- Android Go

  - [Why is the Android Go's performance better?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/228839/44325)

Comment: Need further research: CSC (Country Specific Code)? Feel free to post another answer related to this.

Comment: Regarding [removal of Smart View](https://www.verizon.com/support/knowledge-base-301233/) (need further researched).

Comment: Possible addition: Notification history (One UI Core? Device Model?)