# Samsung Galaxy S22 lock screen: how to revert local and home clocks and reduced notifications?

Tags: samsung, lock-screens

Since reverting the settings on my Samsung Galaxy S22, the lock screen has appeared as shown in the photo below.

[image]

My questions are:

1. How can I revert the clock to only show 'Home' time (instead of 2 clocks)?
2. How can I get expanded notifications on the lock screen (at present I have to click on the notification icon to get more detail.)

I have tried turning off 'Hide content' in 'Lock screen notifications'.
Similarly, I have turned off 'Roaming clock' in 'Lock screen' settings.
Neither of these has had the desired effect.

Comment: Can you try Settings - Lock screen - tap "Edit" on the "Lock screen" image? Then for 2), tap the notification icons and select "Details". For 1), I'm not sure because I can't repro it on M12, but perhaps tapping the clock and seeing if there are customization related to it?

Comment: @AndrewT. Perfect! Thank you! It's easy when you know how.

Comment: Glad to know it helps. Feel free to post a self-answer since I don't know the details, probably due to [the different customization of One UI](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/249616/44325) :)