# On Android 13, is there still a 2G kill switch?

Tags: android-12, cellular-radio, android-13, 2g

A feature was introduced in Android 12 that prohibited 2G usage (except for emergency situations), that’s sometimes called the [2G kill switch](https://www.eff.org/deeplinks/2022/01/victory-google-releases-disable-2g-feature-new-android-smartphones).

However, I now have a Samsung Galaxy A04s and the switch is nowhere to be seen, despite having 2G, 3G and 4G available in the preferred networks menu.

So, was it removed from Android 13 ? Or is there something specific with my phone, my country (France) or my mobile operator (Free) ?

Comment: Have you read that this was not a general feature of Android 12 but is also limited to a "radio HAL 1.6" (which only had Pixel 6 at that time). Even if your phone was released afterwards Samsung heavily modifies the OS so Samsung may simply have decided to use an older HAL. I am not sure what are the minimum requirements for that HAL in Android 12/13.

Comment: This XDA article is on the same topic but has more details: https://www.xda-developers.com/android-12-disable-2g-modem/

Comment: I have Galaxy M12 on Android 13 (OneUI Core 5.1, the same as your device) and there's also no setting for it while it seems [it's available on OneUI 5.x](https://www.reddit.com/r/S22Ultra/comments/y75es0/question_about_the_oneui5_beta_has_samsung/). OneUI Core 5.1 calls `com.samsung.android.app.telephonyui/.netsettings.ui.NetSettingsActivity` while the Activity mentioned on the Reddit is not available (based on testing). My very wild guess is that this option might not be available on [OneUI Core, the stripped-down version of Samsung's OneUI](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/249616/44325).

Comment: Another discussion on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/samsunggalaxy/comments/wpu35j/possibility_to_force_4g_connection/) about forcing 4G rather than disabling 2G while the said feature was also mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for your insights ! Though I wonder why it isn’t present in OneUI Core. I thought OneUI Core was lighter in the sense that it’s stripped of whatever is too demanding or absent from budget hardware, and that looks more software-related… Maybe I should ask directly on the Samsung forums.