# Restore Smart View on a Galaxy phone

Tags: samsung, wifi-direct, android-13, screen-mirroring, miracast

I had an Android (Samsung Galaxy) smartphone with AT&T providing the carrier service. Because AT&T owns DIRECTV, they allow unlimited streaming on their DIRECTV app using AT&T's cellular network data that does not affect your normal internet or hotspot data limits like it would for, say, Netflix.

That allowed me to stream DIRECTV with no data limits or surcharges to my phone over the cellular network while traveling in my RV. I would then use the "Smart View" (Miracast) feature on the phone with my Amazon Firestick/TV to connect the two devices over a direct-WiFi connection (the Firestick has a wireless transmitter/receiver built in to facilitate this connection).

The direct-WiFi connection ability that "Smart View" used was important because the connection used this feature instead of demanding a WiFi connection to the internet over AT&T's network, eating up my data limit, negating the advantage of the unlimited streaming if I was required to access the internet using AT&T's cellular network or hotspot capability.

I recently upgraded to a new Galaxy A14 5G phone running Android 13 to get the benefits of 5G. Samsung/Galaxy, in their infinite wisdom, deleted the "Smart View" functionality, "replacing" it with "SmartThings", which not only requires a WiFi connection to the internet or a special SmartThings hub/router to function, and in addition, it does not support Amazon Firestick or many other devices "Smart View" used to support.

Any help or constructive guidance on how to get "Smart View" or a similar app that only required a direct-WiFi to implement the screen mirroring capability would be appreciated. I have been hunting for such an app for weeks now.

Comment: Welcome to a Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. Looks like [Smart View](https://www.samsung.com/levant/apps/tv/smart-view/) is an independent app that can be installed, is this what you meant? Otherwise, looks like [SmartThings](https://www.samsung.com/us/smartthings/) also includes Smart View, but it's only available on One UI 3.1. [Galaxy A14 5G](https://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_a14_5g-12004.php) on the other hand, is running on One UI *Core*, [the stripped down version which lacks some features](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/249617/44325). Not sure if it's possible.

Comment: Smart View was originally a Samsung app that came installed on my previous phone. The app you linked me to does not look like the Samsung and I believe based on the language used in the app that it was not developed in the US. It also says it contains ads. That said, I am downloading it and will give it a shot!!! I appreciate the link and will let you know how it works out!!!

Comment: I tried the Smart View app you pointed to. It appears it will only work to connect the Android phone to a Sony or Samsung Smart TV. I am trying to connect my phone to an Amazon firestick. Although it can see my firestick when direct-WIFI is on, it will not connect and therefore will not allow me to send my video to the firestick.